# A question about convex domain in$\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: convex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I'm reading Grauert's book：From Holomorphic Functions to Complex Manifolds.
The fourth problem in the exercise on page 8,it needs us to prove that a domain $G$ is convex if and only if for every $z\in\partial G$ there is an affine linear function $\lambda:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda(z)=0$ and $\lambda|_{G}<0$.I don't know how to prove this characterization of convexity of domain,I think it is easy but I need some hint.

Comment: Hint for one direction: If not convex, there are points $a,b,c$ with $a,c\in G$, $b\notin G$ and $b$  between $a$ and $c$. Show there is a $z\in\partial G$ between $a$ and $b$ (inclusive) and that for this $z$, no such $\lambda$ can exist.

Comment: This is a consequence of the [Hahn-Banach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem) Theorem

Comment: @Didier Yes, when I asked this question, I realized that this question is the geometric form of H-B theorem.